# Web app to quickly share pieces of text with other computers?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, sharing, hosted

Is there a web-app that lets me paste some text in and send it to another computer on my network with?

I basically want a really quick and easy way to send my clipboard to another computer -- something like https://send-anywhere.com/, but for text rather than files.

I *do not* want to have to install anything extra; it should work on my browser via a webapp.

Comment: So it may send that clipboard data to a server?

Comment: Are browser addons ok or not? There's http://www.clipbrd.com/ for Chrome. Does it need to preserve formatting of the clipboard or is pure text ok? Don't you think a webapp/browser addon is quite insecure for doing that kind of stuff?

Comment: @ThomasWeller It can send data to a server -- it's just non-sensitive data that doesn't mean anything really. Doesn't need to preserve formatting. Clipbrd seems to sync your clipboard all the time -- I only want to choose when to send my clipboard. (BTW, sorry for the late reply; been a bit busy!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/). It is free, Works on all platforms including android. It also has a web interface.

There is a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pushbullet/chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd?hl=en). And also dedicated installers for all platforms.  You can send text, files etc.

It allows you to send text or files to all devices (1), or a selected device(2).

You can evens send text and files to other people's `PushBullet` if they have a `PushBullet` account.

[image]

Comment: This has a lot of other features - worth checking out. Recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for this task? It may not transfer directly from/to the clipboard, but it is simple enough to work with conveniently. If you need private text transfers I would recommend Google Keep, though keep in mind the contents of your clipboard would be on their servers.

Comment: This was a good option, +1 :) But I found PushBullet easier to use

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Telegram](https://telegram.org). You should create a nickname, and then use it to send a message addressed to yourself (https://telegram.me/YourUsernameHere). Then you can just paste text and receive it everywhere you are logged in, and in particular through web browser (https://web.telegram.org).

Answer (score 0):

Google drive works fine for this, you can even edit the same document from multiple computers on the same time: https://drive.google.com